# Rails 5 change Index Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Should preface this by saying I've never worked with Rails before and this is the first time looking at Ruby and coming from using Node and MEAN stack applications.

- **Ruby:** 2.4.0
- **Rails:** 5.0.2
- `rails new my_api --api`

I have a React frontend application that I would like to run with a Rails API backend. I want these 2 parts to live under the same application directory but keep them separate. I want to run Webpack and all the React things without dealing with the asset pipeline of Rails or using React-Rails or any of that.

The issue I'm running into is serving up the `frontend/dist/index.html` file that contains the entire frontend application.

**Structure**

```
application
  /api
    /app
      /controllers
        application_controller.rb
    /config
      routes.rb
  /frontend
    /dist
      index.html
      bundle.js
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "application#index"
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def index
    render :file => '../frontend/dist/index.html' and return
  end
end
```

What I can tell thus far is Rails will only serve an `index.html` file placed inside of `/public`. If I make another directory inside of `/api` that directory is ignore and always defaults to `/public`.

How can I override the default behavior of looking inside of `/public` and dictate where I want to serve my index file?

Comment: Do you need the to: in the routes.rb?  I think you can just use root 'application#index' Their could be a reason you are using the to: though, I was just wondering.

Comment: I saw a code snippet that had the 'to:'. I can remove and see if that makes a difference. I've been digging through some of the environment configs as another source had suggested to turn 'static_assets' to false but didn't see anything of relevance.

Comment: Static_assets I think will affect it more in production than in the dev environment.  To be honest it probably won't make a big difference excluding the to: I just wondered if there was a reason for it. Cheers